# PHP Insert MySQL Array where one field is an AIl database field created in the first SQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, auto-increment, multiple-tables

On my page we define a new Food Dish, by name, portion size, cost etc. Below that we have a table where you select from a previously defined list of ingredients (another MySQL table) to be assigned to the dish as well as assign an quantity required.

In the first part, the `DishID` is generated automatically (auto increment) on submission, using a trigger on the server side. This inserts the Dishes part successfully.

The second part is where it falls down. I want to post the new `DishID`, `IngID` and `Volume` to my database table, which it does but it leaves my DishID blank.  I am currently using a Select MAX statement so that it brings in the latest record, this may not be ideal but I don't think this is the reason it's not working, as even writing a specified statement to a particular ID, returns blank - therefore it must be something the way my code is written.

```
require_once('db_connect.php');

            $DishName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['DishName']);
            $DishCatID = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['DishCatID']);
            $Serving = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Serving']);
            $SRP = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['SRP']);
            $Method = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Method']);
            $SourceID = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['SourceID']);

            $sql="INSERT INTO Dishes (DishName, DishCatID, Serving, SRP, Method, SourceID)
                  VALUES ('$DishName', '$DishCatID', '$Serving', '$SRP', '$Method', '$SourceID')";
            mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));

            $DishID = 'SELECT MAX(DishID) FROM Dishes';
                        $result=mysqli_query($con, $DishID) or die ("Query to get DishID failed: ".mysqli_error($con));

            $array = array('$DishID'=>(mysql_query($GetDishID)),'$IngID'=>($_POST['IngID[]']),'$Volume'=>($_POST['Volume[]']) );

            $values = array();
            foreach ($_POST['IngID'] as $i => $ingID) {
                if (!empty($ingID)) {
                    $ingID = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $ingID);
                    $volume = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Volume'][$i]);
                    $values[] = "('$DishID', '$ingID', '$volume')";
                }
            }
            if (!empty($values)) {
                $sql2 = 'INSERT INTO DishIng (DishID, IngID, Volume) VALUES ' . implode(', ', $values);
                mysqli_query($con, $sql2) or die(mysqli_error($con));
            }


                require_once('db_disconnect.php');
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [mysqli_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php). It will return the auto generated id used in the last query.

```
$DishID = mysqli_insert_id($con);
```

Comment: That returns '0', how would you apply it?  Maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: Is DishID an auto incremented field? If it's not, then you're going to have to do the select query to get it. But your code fr that is not correct. You create the query in `$DishID` and store the result in `$result` but when you build the array on the next line you call `mysql_query($GetDishID)`. You've been using mysqli and now there is the call to mysql and you never set `$GetDishID` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the insert ID via `mysqli_insert_id()` as the very next thing you do with that database connection after your initial insert statement.  That should look like this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Dishes (DishName, DishCatID, Serving, SRP, Method, SourceID)
      VALUES ('$DishName', '$DishCatID', '$Serving', '$SRP', '$Method', '$SourceID')";
mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
// get inserted row id
$insertID = mysqli_insert_id($con);
```

This is of course assuming that your dish ID field is an autoincrement field.

You also have a `mysql_query()` function call further down in your code that should be changed to `mysqli`.